# setLocation in media recorder android

Tags: android, camera, android-mediarecorder

In my application i am getting address,latitude,longitude using gps. We also required to capture video and set that location to video. so one can see that in video-> detail option.

I am successfully done that with photo but not able to done with video.

I am using Media Recorder for that n try to use setLocation property but for Media recorder object it not shows that property.

what to do???

following is sample code

```
    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);   
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);    
    mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
    mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setOutputFile(path+filename);
    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

First get [Camera Parameters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#using-features). Then use methods [`setGpsLatitude(double latitude)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setGpsLatitude%28double%29) , [`setGpsLongitude(double longitude)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setGpsLongitude%28double%29) on `Parameters` object  to set location etc.

Then set these parameters `mCamera.setParameters(params)`.

Comment: actually i done with that code and also get latitude and longitude for picture. but the problem is i am not getting that when i use Media Recorder. Media recorder contain function getLocation but that is not supported...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MediaRecorder.setLocation()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setLocation%28float,%20float%29) function.